# How to apply a function to all the rows preceeding the current one in an arrayformula?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

So I have the following situation:

[image]

In the first column I have certain values, in the second column, *given a certain row*, I want it to contain the result of a function applied to all the preceeding rows (plus itself) in the 1st column. In this case the function applied is `SUM()`.

The *dumb* approach is the one I used: write the formula in the first row, then copy&paste down till the row you want the function to be applied to.

I want it to be automated, though, and function with as many rows in the given column as there are, even if they are removed or added. I thought I'd use `ARRAYFORMULA()` for this, or `MMULT()` combined with `TRANSPOSE()` as I've seen doing in apparently related examples, but after quite a few tries I'm lost.

Does anybody know how it can be done?

Comment: Perhaps this answer helps you further: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/37839/29140

Answer (score 1):

The following Google Apps Script (GAS) will achieve your goal automatically:

```
function CUMSUM(array) {  
  // set active spreadsheet
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

  // get active sheet
  var sh = ss.getActiveSheet();

  // get data (2D array)
  var aTest = sh.getRange(array).getValues();

  // convert 2D array to 1D array
  var aData = [].concat.apply([],aTest);

  // create new array to hold data
  var aResult = new Array(); 

  // itterate through data range  
  for(var i=0, len=aData.length; i<len; i++) {
    if(i==0) {
      aResult[i] = aData[0];
    } else {
      aResult[i] = aResult[i-1] + aData[i];
    }
  }

  // pass result to formula 
  return aResult;  
}
```

Add this script, via the script editor, to your spreadsheet and the function CUMSUM is available throughout the worksheet, like so: =CUMSUM("A2:A8"). Because an array is returned, use `TRANSPOSE` to get the right positioning.

See example file I've created: [running total](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AluAYY6ZHeWYdFZlM01oWXcwcnZJV2djUVNDOUw3bmc)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but that's not quite what I asked for.

The fact my data is composed of sequential numbers and the fact I apply a sum to them is just for sake of example, but both the data and the function could be anything.

Your approach is specific to the example case I gave, and doesn't even use the first column as a source of data, in fact `ROW(A:A)` expands to a sequence of increasing numbers which is independent of what `A:A` contains at all.

Comment: Oh, I see you've changed your response, now my comment above looks dumb.

The GAS approach could be certanly reused for other other kind of operations (not just the sum, which I restate was just an example), but it wouldn't work for functions that are available only within the spreadsheet (think of slope() and intercept(), which are the ones I actually need).

I would have to reimplement those functions in javascript.

Comment: @FabioA. Please show me an example were you use `slope()` and ` intercept()` (the _dumb_ way). I'm glad I was able to get the running total. There are not many example's to find on the internet....

Answer (score 0):

```
=SUM(B1+A2)
```

Add this to all cells in column; it adds the above number to left number of cell. Doesn't use a script and can be applied to a column at once (just skip the first cell).

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want may be:

for slope:  `=slope(A$1:A1,B$1:B1)`
for intercept:  `=intercept(A$2:A2,B$2:B2)`

though both the above need two sets of data, and based on your question:

for sum:  `=sum(A$2:A2)`

in all cases copied down to suit (including into any added rows).