# SUM of all cells in another column, except above rows

Tags: google-sheets

Each cell in column A should report SUM of every cell of column B, except rows above those cells.

Sample:

```
| A | B |
---------
| 4 | 1 |
| 3 | 0 |
| 3 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 1 | 1 |
| 0 | 0 |
```

How can I achieve this using Google Spreadsheets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is almost the same as a cummulative sum, but reversed.

### Formula

```
=SUM(B2:$B$7)
```

or

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SUMIF(ROW(A2:A7);">="&ROW(A2:A7);B2:B7))
```

### Explained

If you add the first formula in `C2`, then you're able to copy that cell (drag) to `C7`. 
The `ARRAYFORMULA` will present the result at once.

### Example

I've created an example file for you: [Inverse Cummulative Sum](https://docs.google.com/a/familietuinstra.nl/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0ApDwwZxW-IBcdHhodUJadVY2dFNPdmRFS043MUZ3eHc&usp=sharing)

### Reference

[Cummulative Sum](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/46100/29140)