# Conditional Cumulative Sum using Arrayformula

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

I saw a nice solution for the cumulative sum problem here:
[Cumulative Sum without Script](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/37799/cumulative-sum-without-script/46100#46100)

My question is how do you make this conditional? I mean cumulatively sum only numbers that belong to a certain username (string) in a separate column? I'd like to use arrayformula so cells autofill with data without dragging formula manually. E.g. running total for user A:

```
User   Amount   Running Total for A
A        1          1
B        2
A        4          5
A        3          8
B        5
A        2          10
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the data starts in row 2, then try:

`=ArrayFormula(IF(A2:A="A",SUMIF(IF(A2:A="A",ROW(A2:A),ROWS(A:A)+1),"<="&ROW(A2:A),B2:B),))`

Comment: You are a genius, thank you! Works like a charm.

Comment: Is there a way to make this formula work for all elements of column A?... I.e the conditional Running Total will work for a & b, and any other string a users puts into column A?

Comment: @Xzila `=ArrayFormula(IF(LEN(A2:A),SUMIF(IF(LEN(A2:A),ROW(A2:A),ROWS(A:A)+1),"<="&ROW(A2:A),B2:B),))`

Comment: That totals everything. I meant where it has a separate running total for A, and B in the same column. In the original example the last row for User A should have a Running total of 10, and the last row for User B should have a Running total of 7. I asked a similar question to this one, that I've been trying to figure out: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/87492/running-total-in-google-sheets-with-array

Comment: The newest versions of Google Sheets offer an laternative to this solution, AND also offer a solution for those looking for "a separate running total for A, and B in the same column". The answer by @AdamL to Webapps [ArrayFormula to compute running average for groups of rows](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/69855/196152) is an excellent place to start.