# ArrayFormula to calculate stock position by date

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-arrayformula

I am creating a stock transaction tracking sheet where I enter buys and sells etc. I have a formula that can calculate a running position total but I cannot figure out how to convert it to an array formula.

[image]

The formula I have so far is

```
SUM(INDEX(FILTER(A:D, B:B=B2, row(B:B) <= row(B2)),,4))
```

Here's a [copy of the sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/16wFeKcIP-w2QMMIvLRyuDxm1A-9SPjd73zuk7hYjpi8/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want a running sum of values in Column D based on a conditional value in each row of Column B.

Your scenario is VERY similar to this Webapps precedent [ArrayFormula to compute running average for groups of rows](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/69855/196152). In that case, the desired result was a running average. I have modified the accepted answer by @AdamL. I have also added an alternative found on infoinspired

**Assuming all entries in Column B are in sequence (grouped)**

Use this formula:

`=ArrayFormula(IFERROR((SUMIF(ROW(B2:B),"<="&ROW(B2:B),D2:D)-HLOOKUP(0,SUMIF(ROW(B2:B),"<"&ROW(B2:B),D2:D),MATCH(B2:B,B2:B,0),0))))`

**Assuming all entries in Column B are *NOT* in sequence (grouped)**

OPTION#1

`=ArrayFormula(IF(LEN(B2:B),MMULT((ROW(B2:B)>=TRANSPOSE(ROW(B2:B)))*(B2:B=TRANSPOSE(B2:B)),--D2:D),))`

OPTION#2

Solution from infoinspired [Array Formula for Conditional Running Total in Google Sheets](https://infoinspired.com/google-docs/spreadsheet/conditional-running-total-array-formula-google-sheets/#How_to_Add_Conditions_to_Running_Total_Array_Formula)

`=ArrayFormula(MMULT(N(ROW(B2:B7)>=TRANSPOSE(ROW(B2:B7)))*N(B2:B7=TRANSPOSE(B2:B7)),N(D2:D7)))`

---

Note: the `MMULT` function ([Doc ref](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094292)) is often avoided because it can slow down recalculation. It is generally accepted that it is slow with an open ended range (such as B2:B) but faster over a smaller number of rows where the range can be capped (such as B2:B8). [AdamL's answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/69855/196152) should also be read for his discussion of the pros and cons of the "MMULT" vs "non-MMULT" alternatives, including their limitations and effect of processing speed.

---

**Example**

[image: Example]