# Aggregated column based on a pivot table column

Tags: google-sheets

My data set consists of items along with a date attached to each one. I created a pivot table that shows the count items per each year, like this:

```
Year        Count
1976        1
1978        1
1983        1
1984        2
1992        2
2000        1
2002        2
2003        8
2004        2
2005        2
```

I'd like to add another value to the pivot table that shows the aggregate count up to and including that year, so:

```
Year        Count         Aggregate
1976        1             1
1978        1             2
1983        1             3
1984        2             5
1992        2             7
2000        1             8
2002        2            10
2003        8            18
2004        2            20
2005        2            22
```

Any tips?

Comment: Related [Cumulative Sum without Script](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/37799/88163)

Comment: Thanks for the link. I understand I can do this in the source table, but is it possible to do the same on the pivot table?