# ARRAYFORMULA and MAXIFS: does it work like SUMIFS?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-arrayformula

I have an existing formula that is sort of a cumulative MAX of another column: it has a range covering only the rows above it, inclusive.  So B2 is `=MAX(A$1:A2)`, and I can run this down or auto-fill and the range ends on the current row for each one. But I'd much rather use ARRAYFORMULA to cover an indefinitely long column without further edits.

By analogy with AdamL's answer in [Cumulative Sum without Script](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/37799/cumulative-sum-without-script) which I use successfully elsewhere, I am trying: `=ARRAYFORMULA(MAXIFS(A2:A,ROW(A2:A),"<="&ROW(A2:A)))` but my result is an array all equal to the value in A2.  Other values further down in A are larger, but they are not reported as the MAX() in their respective row.

I don't understand how the SUMIFS one worked and this MAXIFS one doesn't, assuming the semantics are similar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use BYROW to expand it as an array formula:

```
=BYROW(A2:A,LAMBDA(each,IF(each="","",MAX(A2:each))))
```

Comment: That works, thanks!

Comment: Then if you're working with two "parallel" ranges you can use MAP. Something like this: `=MAP(B2:B,D2:D,LAMBDA(bcell,dcell,IF(dcell<>"",dcell,MAX(E1,bcell))))` -- obviously, you can adapt the names inside LAMBDA to be more representative of what they actually name

Comment: Ah, you're too fast! I answered my own supplementary question using INDIRECT("D"&ROW(each)).  Thanks again!

Comment: Oh, and MAP can do more than two ranges. Nice!  For posterity, here's my final result, that works, and no INDIRECT(): =MAP(BG2:BG,D2:D,E2:E,LAMBDA(showing,request,nextrally,IF(request<>"",request,IF(nextrally="",,IF(showing="notThisTime",,MAX(E1,nextrally))))))

Comment: You're right! You can add more ranges while they're of the same size. I'm glad it was useful! Consider marking the question as answered ;)

Comment: I tried to, but my reputation as a newbie doesn't permit it. The feedback goes somewhere, it said.  Can you mark your own answer that way?

Comment: No, I can't. I think it's a tick to the left of the answer, but don't worry if you can't either!