# How do I automatically update a cell in Google Spreadsheets to the most recently entered in the same row?

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I am trying to have one column that will show the most recent thing i entered in the row. Example: I want `B2` to be the same as `D2` but once I enter something in `E2` I want `B2` to display that. And then if I entered something in `F3` it would then show in `B2` and so on and so fourth. I figured out how to do it with one cell doing a `"=index(d2)"` and tried something like `"=index(D2:L2)` for the sequence but it only shows `d2` or gets upset and causes errors. I hope that makes sense. It seems simple enough but after researching it I've been unable to find anything. It is mainly text that I am trying to display and not numbers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following little script will add each change you make, in the active row, to column B:

```
function onEdit() {
  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var row = sh.getActiveCell().getRowIndex();
  var value = sh.getActiveCell().getValue();
  sh.getRange(row, 2).setValue(value);
}
```

See example file I created, you you to play around with: [onEdit change](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0ApDwwZxW-IBcdHdfTXJTVWlfQ0pzaV92MHZZNzh4TWc&usp=sharing)

Goto Tools, Script Editor, from the menu and add the script. Make sure to press the two buttons:
[image]