# Data Ranges in Custom Google Spreadsheets Function

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I'm trying to create a custom Function in Google Spreadsheets that takes a range as input parameter.

```
 function Example(cells){
   var values = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRange(cells).getValues();
   var sum = 0;
   for(var i=0;i<values.length;i++){
     sum += values[i][0];
   }
   return [sum];
 }
```

When I try to call Example, I can't use something like `Example(C15:D20)` instead I need to pass the range as string like `Example("C15:D20")`.

The only problem passing range in string format is that **cells are not updated when any of the values in range is updated**.

Is there any work around for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because the `getRange` method only accepts a string as a range. Your problem can be resolved by using just plain JavaScript:

### Code

```
function customSum(range) {
  var sum=0;  
  for(var i=0, iLen=range.length; i<iLen; i++) {
    for(var j=0, jLen=range[0].length; j<jLen; j++) {
      sum += range[i][j];
    }
  }  
  return sum;
}
```

### Example

I've created an example file for you: **[Custom Sum](https://docs.google.com/a/familietuinstra.nl/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0ApDwwZxW-IBcdEZlaXhwT1hCUnkwVDl0LVI1S0xyNFE&usp=sharing)**

### Remark

Please note the difference between the two pieces of code. No API calls are used. The reference you use (cells) has more than one column !! If you want that, then you need to take that into account as well. Also note that changes in the range will be calculated immediately.

Comment: Thanks! Didn't know the ranges were passed to functions as arrays.

Answer (score 0):

This is a workaround that will dynamically update the range references when the range is updated (such as when a new row or column is inserted into it), but still input it as a string to myFunction:

```
=myFunction(CELL("address",A1)&":"&CELL("address",A2))
```

Courtesy of @Nathan Hanna at https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/58179/22521