# How to color an adjacent cell based on a 6-digit hex number without adding the "#"

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, formulas, formatting

I've looked at a few things ([this link](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/docs/88lWZY7WDZI/xW5qVjiUFzoJ), WA's [Colorize a cell in Google Spreadsheets based on cell data](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/48783/colorize-a-cell-in-google-spreadsheets-based-on-cell-data), and [this link](https://gist.github.com/Pathoschild/29ad5ec92348164b1dea)), but haven't been able to quite get the behaviour I want in Google Sheets. What I want to do:

1. Enter six characters (e.g. `00B6FF`) into a cell *without* adding a `#` before them
2. Have the cell to the right of that cell get coloured with the corresponding hex value.

I'm a designer, so not too savvy with the scripts, but I'm up for trying. Tried each of those links above, but the only one I got to work was the gist one, but I don't want it colouring the text.

Can anyone help me figure out how to do this?

Comment: I'm sorry but I had to delete my answer. Apparently, you can't change the background color of a cell as easily as I thought. It can't just be triggered by completing a value in another cell. You need to script a function and then trigger that function from a button on your sheet!

Comment: Questions should be self contained. Please add the relevant content of the external sources, in this case, the gist code.

Answer (score -1):

- add this add-on: **[https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/team-color/ldggbboahhbelionpagpifdnkicagagg?utm_source=permalink)**
- then in **A1** paste **00B6FF**
- and in **B1** paste this formula: **`=IF(A1<>"<>";"#"&A1;)`**

  [image]

Comment: This is the same answer than this other https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/118815/88163 and the same comment that I made to it almost one year ago  it still applies, "The referred extension can't be installed"

Comment: installed today on alt acc and pic taken

Comment: Here are two issues. It's possible that one user can install an add-on and another can't, like limiting an add-on to certain countries, maybe it can be installed by Google regular accounts but not by G Suite accounts. Unfortunately the add-on install page doesn't mention any restriction. The other issue is regarding deleting an answer and posting again exactly the same content as answer to the same question. IMHO that should not be allowed as its looks as some sort of cheating.