# How do I make the color of a cell change if the value has been modified in Google Sheet?

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting

Basically, if the person enters "12" in his/her column, how can I make the cell change to a different color when the same person changes the value again?

This would let other people know if there were changes made.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google Sheets has a built-in feature allows to set formatting rules, it's called Conditional Formatting, but it doesn't has a way to set the comparison of the current value with an old value.

One alternative is to use Google Apps Script, another is to use an add-on.

Using Google Apps Script

If you decide to use Google Apps Script, you could use an on edit trigger. The related event object has a property for the old value and another for the new value, so you could make that your script set a background color if this values are different.

Super simple example

```
function onEdit(e){
  if(e.oldValue && e.value && e.oldValue !== e.value){
    e.range.setBackground('blue');
  }
}
```

A complete script should include a way to limit which cells color should be changed (the previous example will change de color of any edited cell).

NOTES:

This only works for single cell edits, in other words, it will not work when doing a copy/paste of a value or range over another cell/range.

To find an add-on that does what you are looking for, please look at the G Suite Marketplace.

References

- [Use conditional formatting rules in Google Sheets](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/78413?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en)
- [Use add-ons & Apps Script](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/2942256?hl=en)

Related

- [Colorize a cell in Google Sheets based on cell data](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/48783/88163)