# Color cell background automatically if value has changed from original

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, google-apps-script-triggers

Is it possible to automatically color cell backgrounds if their values has been changed (in my case, the only time a cell changes value is by manual user edit/input - no cell values are computed of functions of other cells)?

Comment: Yes, it's possible by using Google Apps Script. For further details please add a brief description of your search/research efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Comment: @Rubén I looked into Conditional Formatting, but none of the presets yielded the desired function.

Comment: You could use the an edit trigger (simple or installable). The edit event object include `value` and `oldValue` properties but only when a single cell is edited, so if you are expecting data being added by copy/pasting multiple cells then you should make a copy of the values somewhere.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I make the color of a cell change if the value has been modified in Google Sheet?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/138045/how-do-i-make-the-color-of-a-cell-change-if-the-value-has-been-modified-in-googl)