# Conditional formatting help with multiple conditions

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting

I have a makeshift production calendar in google sheets that has the date range of product needed and the color of the product (in a drop down list from another sheet. I want to have conditional formatting to highlight the cells between the range the color designated. Each small square has the formula =((IF(AND(Q2>($D4-1),Q2<($G4+1)),"1","0"))) and I was using that to do conditional formatting but could only do one color.

[image: calendar view]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Colorize a cell in Google Sheets based on cell data](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/48783/colorize-a-cell-in-google-sheets-based-on-cell-data)

Comment: Hi and welcome to WebApps. May I try and clarity this; please correct me if I am wrong. In each row, you have a cell containing the Carpet Color (internal string name, not the HEX equivalent). When the conditional formatting rule(s) for that row are satisfied, you want the fill color to be equal to the "Carpet Color". On a tangent, you described a `IF` formula but your snapshot doesn't show the column names for the data elements.