# Range not found error on user-defined function that use a cell reference as argument

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I'm writing a UDF and get an error.  From the documentation, it seems straightforward.  My goal is to check the background color of a cell.  The code is shown below and the calling format is "isColor(cell)".  I get an error (Range not found (line 5, file "Code") on the line `var cell = ...`

I tried to pass the cell address as a string by making the calling format `isColor(cell("address",A2))`

```
function isColor(input) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
  Logger.log(input);
  var cell = sheet.getRange(input);
  var color = cell.getBackground();
  Logger.log(cell);
  color = cell.getBackground(); 
  Logger.log(color);
  var result = false;
  if (color == '#ffffff') {
      result = false;}
      else {
      result = true;
      }
  return result;
}
```

Comment: Related:http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/10629/how-to-pass-a-range-into-a-custom-function-in-google-spreadsheets/92156

Comment: `=isColor(cell("address",A2))` works fine, right?

Comment: It doesn't work.  It always returns true and the log commands provide no information other than "undefined"

Comment: If you are using the debug tool, you should use an auxiliary function to call the main function in order to pass the required arguments, i.e. `function test() {
  isColor('A2');
 } `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Short answer

Google Sheets pass custom function arguments as values, not as objects, in this case not as a cell/range.

## Workaround

Use SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange().getFormula() to get the cell formula and extract the reference from it.

### Example

Note: Custom functions recalculates when their arguments changes their values. Changing the background of the referenced cell will not make that Google Sheets recalculate them.

```
function isColor(input) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
  var activeRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange();
  var activeSheet = activeRange.getSheet();
  var formula = activeRange.getFormula();
  try {
    var rangeA1Notation = formula.match(/=\w+\((.*)\)/i)[1].split('!');
  } catch(e) {
    throw new Error('The reference isn\'t valid');
  }
  //
  Logger.log(rangeA1Notation);
  var cell = sheet.getRange(rangeA1Notation);
  var color = cell.getBackground();
  Logger.log(cell);
  color = cell.getBackground(); 
  Logger.log(color);
  var result = false;
  if (color == '#ffffff') {
      result = false;}
      else {
      result = true;
      }
  return result;
}
```

## Explanation

In the Google Sheets / Google Apps Script argot, [user-defined functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User-defined_function) are called [custom functions](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions).

From the custom functions official documentation:

> ### Data types
>
> Google Sheets stores data in different formats depending on the nature
>   of the data. When these values are used in custom functions, Apps
>   Script treats them as the appropriate data type in JavaScript. These
>   are the most common areas of confusion:
>
> - Times and dates in Sheets become [Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) objects in Apps Script. If the spreadsheet and the script use different time zones (a rare problem),
>     the custom function will need to compensate.
> - Duration values in Sheets also become Date objects, but [working with them can be complicated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17715841/gas-how-to-read-the-correct-time-values-form-google-spreadsheet).
> - Percentage values in Sheets become decimal numbers in Apps Script. For example, a cell with a value of 10% becomes 0.1 in Apps Script.

IMHO the documentation should include a note regarding cell/range references as the Spreadsheet service includes [Range](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range) as class.

Comment: Thanks!  I didn't see any documentation about how difficult it is to pass an argument to a UDF.  How would I handle the formula referencing a cell on a different sheet?

Comment: @JohnFaig: Does this answer was helpful for you? It was "updated" by the "community user".

Answer (score 1):

I found some different partially workaround, it's not perfect but I think I could be helpful:
instead of sending as a parameter I sent it as a string, for example, when choosing the range it will be =example(a1:a3) I used: example("a1:a3") when I first selected the range and then changed it manually.