# How do I get the address of a range with a formula?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

Let's say I have a range called `WidgetTypes` in cells `C5:M5`.

I want my formula in cell `A1` to return `C5:M5` or `$C$5:$M$5`.

What formula goes into cell `A1`?

`cell("address",WidgetTypes)` returns `$C$5` but I'm stuck there. I can't get the whole thing.

EDIT

I tried:

```
function getRangeAddress(range) {
  return range.getA1Notation();
}
```

and I passed in my named range, like this:

```
=getRangeAddress(WidgetTypes)
```

but I got the error:

> TypeError: Cannot find function getA1Notation in object
>   Kitchen,Entry,Living Room,Dining Room,Breakfast Room,Master
>   Bedroom,Bedroom,Full Bath,Half Bath,Utility Room,Garage. (line 2).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't a built-in function that returns the address of a named range. One alternative is to use a custom function.

The custom function should parse the cell formula to get the name of the named range then the code code could use that string to get the related range and after that you could use `getA1Notation`.

Related

- [How to pass a range into a custom function in Google Spreadsheets?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/10629/88163) (see [this answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/92156/88163) )

References

- [Extending Google Sheets](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets)
- [Custom functions](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions)

Comment: When you say "that string", do you mean the string `WidgetTypes`?

Comment: @toddmo I'm referring "to the name of the named range", if the name of named range is `WidgetTypes`, then yes.

Comment: Thanks, was just making sure. So then you say use `WidgetTypes` (the string) to "get the related range" (in order to use `getA1Notation`. If "the related range" I want to get is C5:M5, are you saying `getA1Notation` is going to return "C5:M5"?

Comment: @toddmo I added a couple of references. Please read them, after that if still have questions, please let me know.

Comment: ok I got it working, see my answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I added the custom function:

```
function getRangeAddress(namedRange) {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var range = sheet.getRange(namedRange);  
  return range.getA1Notation();
}
```

and to use it, I did

```
=getRangeAddress(WidgetTypes)
```

and it returns `C5:M5` as a string.

Answer (score 0):

In order to return the range `$C$5:$M$5` you can use the following formula:

```
=ADDRESS(5,3)&":"&ADDRESS(5,13)
```

*Make a note that when using the function ADRRESS we refer to cell eg.`C5` but we first write the row number `5` and then the column number`3`*.

You cannot use the function CELL to get the range of your Named range `WidgetTypes`.

**Why do I get those results?**
The syntax for CELL is: `CELL(info_type, reference)`.
In your case, when giving as `reference` your named range `WidgetTypes` (which actually is `C5:M5`) and asking for `info_type` the `"address"`, the formula correctly *"returns an absolute reference as plain text of the top left cell in `reference`"* which is `C5`

You can read about the type of information you are allowed to use as well as what results you can expect from CELL in the [Official Google Documentation](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3267071?hl=en-GB) page.

Comment: I don't have a `13` handy to work with. I just have the range reference `WidgetTypes`. So how would I get the number 13 (Column M)? That's where I'm stuck, actually. The end of WidgetTypes won't always be M or 13. It may grow or shrink.